# neo4j: how to efficiently search value in list?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to build a graph db with massive amount of nodes and relations. every node should hold a list of string values and I need to be able to query all the nodes connected to a starting node, that have a given value in their list.

for example, I might have a node with a list of ["dog", "cat", "bird"], and I might need to query all nodes that have the value "dog" in their list.

now my question is this - what would be more efficient solution for that list in neo4j?

1. hold the values as an actual list, and search value inside that list during the query?
   or...
2. instead using a list property, implement the list as separated properties and use HAS(n.property) to find all the nodes with a property?
3. other solution?

what would be the most efficient way (for lots of queries)?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement list as seperate property, taht is the efficient way to handle large amount of data.

Then you can access data e.g

```
MATCH (n:node) where n.property = {SearchValue} return n;
```

Implementing list is not a good idea.